# How do I loop though all the minutes between two times?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code

```
Dim Today As Date
Today = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")

Dim startminute As Date
Dim minuteincrease As Double

For i = 0 To 540
    minuteincrease = i
    startminute = Today & " 08:00:00" + minuteincrease
Next i
```

I want to loop through all the minutes from 08:00 to 17:00.

Example. Today it would be from "2020-02-25 08:00:00" to "2020-02-25 17:00:00"

The first iteration would give 2020-02-25 08:00:00.

The second 2020-02-25 08:01:00 and so on.

But I'm not sure how to use "i" to add one minute.

Anyone have an idea?

/Jens

Comment: `... + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timeserial-function

Comment: Another way: `DateAdd("n", Date, 1)`

Comment: `startminute = Today & " 08:00:00" + minuteincrease` - concatenation and addition look off in that line.

Comment: or `+ i / (24*60)`

Comment: `Today = Date`, not `Today = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")`.

Comment: Thank you! I went with timeserial! This did the trick  `startminute = startminute + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)`